# Display information about the number of answers

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

I can often see code-only or link-only answers show up in the moderation tools, usually flagged as *low quality* (more appropriate), and many times as *not an answer* (which is just crazy).

While I agree that code-only and link-only answers are not the highest quality posts in general, I would specially avoid deleting them if they happen to be the **only** answer posted for the given question.

The UI doesn't make it very easy to extract this information (even if you expand the post, that view only contains the question), you have to visit the question in a new tab and scroll through.

I think it would be a good idea to show the number of answers in some form on the moderation screen (at least in the expanded view).

Comment: You can click on the link. IIRC?

Comment: I'm doing `CTRL+Click on the link` > `change tab` > `scroll through` > `close tab`. I don't think `Click on the link` > `scroll through` > `back button` is much simpler either.